# How to pass a GlobalKey field from one class to another?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and dart in general. While I was working with a form inside a Stateful Widget state, I wanted to continue the form on another tab in the UI. To do this I would need to pass the form's key to another class.

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you add the related code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you instantiate a GlobalKey in a parent widget of the widgets that need to reuse a state object, then pass it down to all of them them via the ‘key’ parameters of their constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Parent Class:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
  drawer: const MyDrawer(),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: height * 0.20,
              color: AppColor().primary,
              child: Header(Globalkey: _scaffoldKey,),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
));
}
}
```

Second Class:

```
class Header extends StatelessWidget {
final Globalkey;
Header({required this.Globalkey});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      top: 5,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () => Globalkey.currentState?.openDrawer(),
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 30,
              )),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
}
```